# remove elements from a List of case class structure efficiently and elegantly

Tags: scala, lenses, monocle-scala

I have a nested `case` classes structure in a `List`

for simplicity will use following as an example -

```
case class Address(street: String, city: String, state: String, zipCode: Int)
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, addresses: List[Address])
case class Department(people: List[Person])
```

say there is `List[Department]` ; now if I wan to create a new `List[Department]` by filtering `Address` for each `Person` which doesn't have a specific `zipCode` value ; traditionally we can do following

```
def filterPersonsByAddress(dlist: List[Department]): List[Department] = {
  dlist.map { d =>
    val people = d.people.map { p => 
      p.copy(addresses = p.addresses.filterNot(_.zipCode == 38978))}
      d.copy(people=people)
    }
 }
```

This approach is not performant as depending on the nesting level it can be Big O(n^2) or Big O(n^3) ;

I am trying to learn Lenses via [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle). So far what I have learned is Lenses is useful when you have to "modify" a deeply nested `case` class structure but haven't yet found a way to "chop off" certain part of nested structure based on a condition and return a new structure. Is this possible for via Monocle? Also I am not sure if Lenses will be able to help in achieving better Big O time as well?

Comment: Given in order to determine if a departmentshould be in the new dept you have to look at all addresses of all people, then I don't see how it can be anything but O(#d * #p * #a).

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul : not disagreeing with your comment. That may leave out "efficient" part of the question; still looking for an elegant way to do this to see if Lenses/Monocle can help there. do you know?

Comment: Read about concept called `Lenses`. Some libraries like Monocle/scalaz implement it.

Comment: @Maxim, er, yes, the OP did already say that in the question!

Comment: @VikasPandya, why all the copies/chopping? Why in your use-case does it make sense to filter out the other address of people, rather than regard a person's record as immutable and just produce a list of people with at least one address with the right zip code? You'd seem to be be giving yourself a future issue with working out which Person object captures the current details of that person correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is essentially equivalent to your implementation in terms of performance, but it's arguable clearer:

```
import monocle.Traversal, monocle.macros.GenLens
import monocle.function.all._, monocle.std.list._

val deptAddresses: Traversal[Department, List[Address]] =
  GenLens[Department](_.people)
    .composeTraversal(each)
    .composeLens(GenLens[Person](_.addresses))

val filterAddresses: Department => Department =
  deptAddresses.modify(_.filterNot(_.zipCode == 38978))
```

This just builds a traversal to navigate to each person's list of addresses so that you can modify it based on the predicate. I'm not sure there's a better way to perform the filtering (since zip codes don't serve as unique indices), but maybe Julien will weigh in with one.